# Good practices of writing and unit testing Utility methods in scala

Tags: scala, mockito, scalatest

In particular situations, you need to have some utility methods that are required across different classes. To solve this situation, you create an Util object wherein you place all these methods

```
object AggregatorUtil {
  def aggregateValues(list : List[BigDecimal]) = //some logic...
}

// Import everything in the Utilities object
import AggregatorUtil._
```

and then import whichever members of util are required in your class. However, the downside to this is that, as all your methods are inside the singleton object and **it becomes tricky to mock the object and unit test methods of the class that use utility methods.**

To solve this problem again, the only solution that came to mind was **Extracting the functionality out to a trait and then mocking the trait.**

Please let me know if there is any other approach for handling and testing of util methods and which one is a rather cleaner approach.

Thanks in advance !!!

Note: -I am using scalatest and mockito in my project.

Comment: Why would it be hard to test the methods in the object? or you mean testing the methods that use that `import AggregatorUtil._`

Comment: I am trying to test the methods that use AggregatorUtil methods.

Comment: Why would you possibly want to use mocking here? Mocking isn't some kind of goal in itself—sometimes it may be a necessary evil, but any time you can avoid it you absolutely should.

Comment: I agree with @TravisBrown, if those util functions are small utilities that are properly tested, pure functions and used inside another method then is a private call and your unit test should not know they exist. Now, if they are dependencies accessing external resources or they do some complex calculation then they shouldn't be modeled as utilities in an object but as dependencies, and that would be an appropiate use of mocking

Comment: I disagree with the sentiment of avoiding mocking "when you can". It certainly makes sense to not mock completely trivial stuff without any external dependencies or complex logic, but that's just common sense. Outside of that, I'd say, one should mock out _everything_ that can be mocked. Having said that, the actual question sounds like an XY-problem: `he only solution that came to mind was Extracting the functionality out to a trait` - you HAVE the solution, but are asking for another one without even mentioning what's wrong with it. Is it just curiosity?

Comment: @Dima this question was to focus on best practice and any other way than extracting to a trait. This was indeed out of curiosity. However, I was not able to explain the question properly and this probably led to some people downvoting my question

Comment: @ChaitanyaWaikar no, I think, the downvoting is because opinion-based  (aka "best practices") and "curiosity" questions are off-topic here. Check [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for a description of what kinds of questions are considered "good".

Answer (score 1):

If you *need* to mock, putting this all in a mocked-out trait is the way forward. If mocking is unnecessary though, avoid it. Mocking unnecessarily is... unnecessary. You'll just be wasting time and effort for something which provides no additional value.

Mocking is best used when you have complex functionality or functionality in other files which you want to treat as a [black box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_box) and just assume it works as expected (you'd then typically unit test this stuff separately). If you can avoid it and use the functions' *actual* functionality though, you'll get a much more realistic view of what your application does and will spot new bugs/breaking changes quicker (if you have mocked out functionality and forget to update your mocks, you might not any spot new bugs you introduce).

A good example of when mocking is necessary is when you're mocking calls to a database in a MVC application (e.g. a Scala Play microservice). You obviously don't want to have to run an actual database when testing your code, so you'd typically mock out your connector layer and return dummy/mocked data from your connector functions.

An example of something you wouldn't mock is something like:

```
trait MyTrait {
  def toInt(str: String): Int
}

val mockedTrait = mock[MyTrait]
when(mockedTrait.toInt(eq("3")).thenReturn(3)
```

It's a bit of a silly example, but I think it explains the point clearly - doing something like this would be ridiculous. Mocking isn't always the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I mostly mock with `Test-Implementation` which I find more readable and you don't have to learn a mocking framework.

Here an example:

The Interface:

```
trait DataRepo {

  def persist(data: DataObject): Future[DataObject]

  def idents(): Future[List[String]]

  def insertData(dataCont: DataObject): Future[Int]
  ...
}
```

The Mocked Interface:

```
object DataRepoMock extends DataRepo {

  def persist(data: DataObject): Future[DataObject] = ??? // only implement when needed

  def idents(): Future[List[String]] = Future.successful((0 to 10).map(_=>Random.nextInt(100)))

  def insertData(dataCont: DataObject): Future[Int] = Future.successful(Random.nextInt(100))
  ...
}
```

You can also use all the Scala goodies, like Pattern Matching, to make your Mock react differently to input.

Here is an example that this is not just used by myself;):
 [EPFLx: scala-reactiveX](https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:EPFLx+scala-reactiveX+1T2019/course/) see *Lecture 2.5 Testing Actor Systems*:

```
  def fakeGetter(url:String, depth: Int):Props =
    Props(new Getter(url, depth){
      override def webClient: WebClient = FakeWebClient
    })
```

Comment: Why would you waste time and introduce possible errors in the test by implementing a complex mock class to cater for all the needs of different scenarios when you can use a mocking framework and declare its behaviour in a declarative way on a per test/scenario basis?

Comment: @Bruno I added an example that nicely shows situation where this approach makes sense.

Comment: My point is you have lot of lines of code, probably with logic to pick the right answer if you have to cater for more than one test, and that code is away from the test itself (as it has to be reused) hampering its redability. If you use a mocking framwork you can create the mock and stub a return value in a declarative way (and in just 2 lines), right in the test setup, so you reading the test is more clear and your overall code is shorter and not as error prone